# Error array php

Tags: php, wordpress, php7, php5

Estoy ejecutando una función en `php`:

```
cmb2_get_field_value($metabox_id, $field_id, $object_id, $object_type = 'post');
```

Pero en el `field_id` en la documentación pone esto:

> Field ID or all field arguments.

Si pongo el id me funciona, pero como puedo hacer para ponerlos todos?

Esta es la documentación: https://cmb2.io/api/function-cmb2_get_field_value.html

Comment: Creo que se refiere a todos los argumentos del `field` que quieras pasar. Por ejemplo: `$field_args=array ('id'=>1, 'name'=>'ElNombre', 'type'=>'ElTipo');` y en la llamada: `cmb2_get_field_value($metabox_id, $field_args, $object_id, $object_type = 'post');`